# Cloud Computing IaaS Tools

Tags: cloud-computing

I would like to know which other tools can help me to set up a private cloud infrastructure but still allow me to connect with services like Amazon EC2 or S3. The ones I know about are:

- Nimbus
- Open QRM
- OpenNebula
- Eucalyptus

Comment: Unfortunately, your question seems off-topic here, but on the http://softwarecs.stackexchange.com it would have probably a much better chance to a long-term survival.

Answer (score 1):

VMware recently released VMware vCloud. Basically it's a combination of the available Vmware technologies with a nice and easy to use web interface.

http://www.vmware.com/products/vcloud/

Answer (score 1):

Eucalyptus support Amazon EC2 Api so you theoretically you should be able to use Eucalyptus along with Amazon EC2/S3 using the same interface.

Answer (score 1):

- [OpenStack](http://openstack.org)
- [Apache CloudStack](https://cloudstack.apache.org/) (with Citrix CloudPlatform as the commercially supported version)

Both of them support Amazon's EC2 and S3 APIs.